# Azure sql server / xamarin mobile app: how to capture userID for audit trail

Tags: sql-server, azure, xamarin, triggers, audit-trail

I've a Xamarin mobile app front end on Azure SQL Server database but currently unable to determine the identity of the mobile app user in a SQL Server trigger for audit trail.

In a locally hosted IIS .NET website on SQL Server design CONTEXT_INFO returns the web app user ID originating from AspNetUsers as expected, but in the sample ToDoItem Azure mobile app, putting CONTEXT_INFO in a trigger returns the Session Tracing ID.

I want the UserID or username (sid / stable id) used to login to the mobile app.

#### SQL :

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), CONTEXT_INFO())
```

#### Sample output :

```
B0854901-5B55-4C6C-A0C9-B3B757BF3303
```

Any ideas how to get a user ID in the trigger?